# What solutions are there against deep stalls?

Tags: aircraft-systems, stall

What solutions are there against [deep stalls](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/q/8022/14897)?

According to [SKYbrary](https://www.skybrary.aero/index.php/Deep_Stall):

> Aircraft with a T-tail design are often configured with a **Stick Pusher** system to help prevent the mainplane angle of attack from reaching a value that could result in a Deep Stall.

Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Airbus A400M military transport was equipped with a [rocket engine](https://www.flightglobal.com/news/articles/airbus-zero-major-issues-from-a-m-flight-tests-337517/) pointing downward which could produce a 5-second burn during testing of deep stall characteristics. It isn’t standard equipment though.

Answer (score 5):

[image]
(Source: [YouTube](https://youtu.be/vsRxWspTTJI), composite of two frames)

I came across this interesting, probably unique, solution:

With the heavier engines on the [MD-90](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonnell_Douglas_MD-90) compared to the MD-80, MDC added flaps on the engine pylons that activate (deflect 30°) to assist in recovering from deep stalls.

> The first warning of stall onset comes from the stick-shaker, followed by a red light and aural/vocal warning, and the stall is finally corrected by a stick-pusher. The nacelle strakes and large engine pylon assist natural pitch- down at the stall. The pylon trailing edge also deflects 30° down when the control column is pushed fully forwards: this deflection takes about 2s (*[Flight](https://www.flightglobal.com/FlightPDFArchive/1994/1994%20-%202604.PDF),* 1994).