# Picking a NACA airfoil for a new propeller on a DJI drone?

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, engineering

The idea is to design a fairly simple propeller using Fusion software program that has a CONSTANT airfoil throughout (but that twists or changes in scale as it spans). I want a large coefficient of lift (Cl) to coefficient of drag ratio (Cd). The Reynolds number should be about 28k. Calculated at radius=75% where the blade is most efficient at generating lift. Problem is the airfoiltools.com website shows the Cl to Cd graphs in a way that is not so easy to read. There is also no way to search through the output of the visual graphs. And I imagine scraping a visual thing like a Cl to Cd graph would be complicated. Any help? Regards

Comment: [This](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/48847/how-do-i-choose-the-correct-airfoil) might help

Answer (score 0):

Regarding tools:

- Digitizing data from plots is feasible, but it requires human effort.
- The Airfoiltools website utilizes Xfoil, a free software that enables you to generate the necessary data (CL/CD) with **any geometry**. It may take some time to become accustomed to it.

Regarding the design-process:

- Commercial drones are already optimized for a specific mission profile. If you need to increase the performance, be aware that you may hit other bottlenecks (battery, motors, software, controller, propeller clearance, etc).
- Assuming you're going to 3D-print the propellers, remember that you'll also have structural/mechanical constraints.
- A basic testing bench might help more than Xfoil and the optimization process you may try, if you have not designed propellers before.

If this is a class-work please share your current work and approach a bit more.

Tip: Comparing best CL/CD ratios is simple with human eye, or taking note of the top-left-most point and writing its CL and CD figures down.